Robotjs issues on windows VM on AWS
It's an unusual problem, I have installed robot-js on an ec2 instance which runs using a Windows server. The code is pretty simple, it navigates and clicks on two instances.
robot.moveMouse(385, 150);
robot.mouseClick();
await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
robot.moveMouse(573, 446);
robot.mouseClick();

The code is running with the playwright module so ignore the timeout bit. It's run simply using the node filename. It works perfectly fine as long as I am active on the VM when I disconnect the session the code keeps running and the playwright piece is working fine but the robot-js bit doesn't work. This means it just freezes until the timeout on the whole function is called and goes to catch block.
It's just strange. Any clue?
